# Python Curses initscr Error

Tags: python, curses

I'm trying to initiate

```
screen = curses.initscr()
```

But it failed and returns

```
File "C:\Python32\lib\curses\__init__.py", line 31, in initscr
fd=_sys.__stdout__.fileno())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

Here's my system Python 3.2.3 (default, Apr 11 2012, 07:12:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

This is my first time running python on this computer, it's Windows 7 64bit.

Is this has something to do with my OS? Anyway I can solve this?

Comment: Are you using the curses module from --> http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#curses ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `curses` module on Windows; apparently there are DOS and OS/2 ports but it is primarily a POSIX-only library.

You'll have to use a Windows-specific port such as [`wcurses`](http://code.google.com/p/wcurses/), a third-party project that supports Windows too such as [PDCurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/), or you could try the [`console` module](http://www.effbot.org/zone/console-handbook.htm) (the latter drives the Windows CMD console in a similar manner).

Comment: Interesting; that is a packaging of the [PDCurses library](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/), not `curses`. In essence, it is a port like `wcurses`.

Comment: Added that to my post; I wasn't aware of that project.

Answer (score 0):

There are curses extension down-loads available for almost all the Python versions on Windows. I had the same error as Pieters but it stemmed from the fact I was trying to run the program from Idle. That doesn't work, apparently, when using an extension like curses. Just left click on your .py program and it will make its own call to Python and its extensions and this error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IDLE, you can't use curses. If you want curses with IDLE, start it with the following .bat file:

```
echo Waiting for starting program
python -m idlelib
```

It redirects curses to cmd window