# Curses returning AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'initscr'

Tags: python, curses

I am following the [Curses programming HowTo on the Python site](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html), but I am running into a rather bizarre issue.

My code is currently very short, doesn't actually do anything **because** of this error, I haven't been able to move on. Here's my code:

```
import curses
#from curses import wrapper

stdscr = curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()
curses.cbreak()

stdscr.keypad(True)

def main(stdscr):

    begin_x = 20; begin_y = 7
    height = 5; width = 40
    win = curses.newwin(height, width, begin_y, begin_x)

    stdscr.refresh()
    stdscr.getkey()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    wrapper(main)
```

and the Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "curses.py", line 1, in <module>
    import curses
  File "/home/nate/Documents/Programming/Python/curses.py", line 4, in <module>
    stdscr = curses.initscr()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'initscr'
```

I commented out the `from curses import wrapper` because that was giving me another error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "curses.py", line 1, in <module>
    import curses
  File "/home/nate/Documents/Programming/Python/curses.py", line 2, in <module>
    from curses import wrapper
ImportError: cannot import name wrapper
```

but I suppose that would be another question.

I am following the tutorial word for word right now, to learn curses, but currently the only thing it's making me do is use curses directed at Python :P.

I am running Python 3.3.2 on Ubuntu 13.10, so [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13434514/python-curses-initscr-error) has nothing to do with this, as he was using Windows and I am not (thankfully :D)

Why am I not able to do this? I'm copying it directly from the Python site, so you'd think it would work!

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You named your file `curses.py`, so Python thinks that file is the `curses` module. Name it something else.

Comment: Oh of course...I can't believe I did that :P Thanks :D

Comment: If the error persists, check for a `curses.pyc` file in the same folder, and delete it.

Comment: Why did I do exactly the same? 

Answer (score 3):

`mv curses.py someOtherName.py`

If you get the same error, try removing any `.pyc` files.

In this case it would be `rm curses.pyc`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is essentially a duplicate of the one above. :)

Comment: kind of, but one may forget to remove the .pyc file .. in that case same error comes

Comment: That is true. I was thinking you should have made this a comment, but you can't do that until you've got 50 rep.